# hide or show a button for authenticated user in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

i want to show "Become Tutor" button if
1. the user is not logged in.
2. the logged in user is not already tutor.

otherwise i want to show "Tutor DashBoard" button.(for user already tutor)
the code works but it shows "Tutor DashBoard" for all logged in users even if they are not already tutor.i hope you understand.
here is code

```
 //BecomeTutor to show or hide
        const BecomeTutor=(props)=>{

            const user=localStorage.getItem('user')
            console.log("user:"+user);// this shows right user on console

              if(!user){
                return(  
                    <div>   
            <a  href="NewTutorForm" onClick={()=>onCreate()}><Button 
               variant="contained"
               color="primary" >Become a Tutor </Button></a>

                    </div>
                );}


                else{
            const check= props.tutorList.find(x=>x.UserId==user.id)
            console.log("tutorList:", props.tutorList);
            console.log("check:"+ check); // to show tutor on console

            if ( check ){
                return(  
                    <div>   
            <a  href="TutorDashBoard" onClick={()=>tutorDashBoard(check.UserId)}><Button 
               variant="contained"
               color="primary" >Tutor DashBoard </Button></a>

                    </div>
                );
                }
                else{
                    return(  
                        <div>   
                <a  href="NewTutorForm" onClick={()=>onCreate()}><Button 
                   variant="contained"
                   color="primary" >Become a Tutor </Button></a>

                        </div>
                    ); 
                }
            }

        }
```

value of user on console:

```
user: {"id":6,"username":"fiazranjha","email":"fiazmianwal@gmail.com","role":"user","token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6IjYiLCJuYmYiOjE1OTA1ODM2MTMsImV4cCI6MTU5MTE4ODQxMywiaWF0IjoxNTkwNTgzNjEzfQ.J7JWakYMMAwZN02xwOOGBLsagFs_oGbqUAr1aWsGiIk"}
```

value of tutorList on console:

```
tutorList: [{…}]0: address: "1km mianwal road kuthiala sheikhan"category: "OnlineTutor"courses: []experience: "this is test"fullName: "fiaz ahmed"mobile: "03466469074"qualification: "test"tutorId: 2updatedOn: "2020-05-26T04:34:52.5088619"userId: 6username: "fiazranjha"whatsapp: "03466469074"__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array(0)]
```

value of check on console

```
check: {tutorId: 2, fullName: "fiaz ahmed", username: "fiazranjha", userId: 6, mobile: "03466469074", …}address: "1km mianwal road kuthiala sheikhan"category: "OnlineTutor"courses: []experience: "this is test"fullName: "fiaz ahmed"mobile: "03466469074"qualification: "test"tutorId: 2updatedOn: "2020-05-26T04:34:52.5088619"userId: 6username: "fiazranjha"whatsapp: "03466469074"__proto__: Object}
```

Comment: Can you give us what tutorList returns?

Comment: Can you share the tutorList data and user data? Also for  console.log("check:"+ check); you are casting the object to string, so you are getting check:[object object]
, you can try console.log("check", check)

Comment: I cant see much, can you lost it in your main post and format is so we can actualy read?

Comment: @DamianBusz  i am editing the question in just a minute please wait.

Comment: hi @DamianBusz i have updated the question .the UserId is 6 in `tutorList` , id is 6 in `user` and UserId in check also 6. but it show `TutorDashboard` for other users also.for example user with id 5 also access the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the error .the type of user was string .type of tutorList was object .`console.log("user:",typeof(user));` changed the user to object by `JSON.pars()`. thankful to all specially @Khabir his indication for lower case userId was also helpful. following changing  worked like a charm.

```
 //BecomeTutor to show or hide
        const BecomeTutor=(props)=>{

            const user=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
            console.log("user:",user);

              if(!user){
                return(  
                    <div>   
            <a  href="NewTutorForm" onClick={()=>onCreate()}><Button 
               variant="contained"
               color="primary" >Become a Tutor </Button></a>

                    </div>
                );}

                else{
            const check= {...props.tutorList.find(x=>x.userId==user.id)}
            console.log("tutorList:", props.tutorList); // to show
            console.log("check:",check); // to show

            if ( check.userId ){
                return(  
                    <div>   
            <a  href="TutorDashBoard" onClick={()=>props.tutorDashBoard(check.userId,check)}><Button 
               variant="contained"
               color="primary" >Tutor DashBoard </Button></a>

                    </div>
                );
                }
                else{
                    return(  
                        <div>   
                <a  href="NewTutorForm" onClick={()=>onCreate()}><Button 
                   variant="contained"
                   color="primary" >Become a Tutor </Button></a>

                        </div>
                    ); 
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please replace

```
const check = props.tutorList.find(x => x.UserId == user.id)
```

with

```
const check = props.tutorList.find(x => x.userId == user.id)
```

because, tutorList hold the property `userId` not `UserId`. Also you need to change the following function call

```
tutorDashBoard(check.UserId)
```

as

```
tutorDashBoard(check.userId)
```

Comment: hi @khabir if i change UserId to userId ,the chek becomes  undefined.as you suggest ,the console shows all properties lower case.but userId does not work rather UserId assign correct value to check.in inner if statement i also tried by replacing check with check.UserId==user.id   please help i am stuck here.

Comment: but there is lower case `userId` in the json of  tutorList that you provided. I will try my level best to help but please double check the userId in tutorList josn and userId in your code. both must be matched

Comment: Hi @khabir i am stuck on the same code.i am trying every option.using userid gives undefined. please help.

Comment: can u pls share your full code. if your api is live then I can reproduce your issue. it is very hard to give solution unless I reproduce it.